# write data to file with persistent storage, swift

Tags: swift, core-data, writetofile

I used core data for storing user information, and I tried to write the measurement data (coming from built-in accelerometer) by using "writeToFile".

The core data functioned well with persistent storage of the user data; however, those measurement data file stored by "writeToFile" would just gradually disappear after a long period/newer files were written.

Should I use SQLite or any other database for storing the file of measurement data? Or is it possible to use core data to store files (it seems not achievable though)? I would like to keep both the user data and measurement data into a persistent storage. Thanks for suggestions!!

```
func writeToFile () {

    let firstName = String(trial!.project!)
    let secondName = String(trial!.record!)


    let exportFilePath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "\(firstName)_\(secondName).csv"
    let exportFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: exportFilePath)!
    NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(exportFilePath, contents: NSData(), attributes: nil)
```

Update:
Problem solved by using "NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory". The final code looks like this:

I'm not really sure if you need to state "createDirectoryAtURL" or if the file can be created anyway.

```
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: NSURL(), create: true, error: nil)

NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtURL(documentsURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: nil)

let fileURL = documentsURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(firstName).csv")

NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(fileURL.path!, contents: NSData(), attributes: nil)

let fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL: fileURL, error: nil)
if let fileHandle = fileHandle {
...
fileHandle.writeData(csvData!)
...
```

Comment: I'm still learning this stuff myself, but does it have to do with where you are storing the file? (Is it a temporary location?). Again, I'm not familiar with these classes, but it is named `NSTemporaryDirectory()`, which seems that it would be temporary by nature.

Comment: Please show your platform. iOS? Sandboxed Mac (App Store app)? Or free Mac app?

Comment: Hi @Fluidity thanks for your suggestion! Yes I also found out that was the problem.. I was trying to look for other solutions to create the path for a file and write data in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `NSTemporaryDirectory` to store your files. The whole point of that directory is that the files are **temporary**, meaning that the operating system is free to delete them. You say they disappear after "a long period"; that's exactly the intended behavior with `NSTemporaryDirectory`.

If you need to keep the files around, you should use the `urls(for:in:)` method on `NSFileManager` to get the location of the documents directory (`.documentDirectory`).

Comment: "That page cannot be found". If you ask for the documents directory, it's persistent until the user deletes your app or the phone gets erased. Any files in the documents directory are automatically backed up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out! I need a bit time to find out how to implement your suggestions on urls() method. Will come back later to choose your answer if it works well!

Comment: Thanks again for quick response! It's midnight over here so I will try it tomorrow ;)

Comment: Finally it worked out well! Thanks! I've used ` let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: NSURL(), create: true, error: nil) ` to create the URL. Strange that ApplicationDirectory doesn't work well (return nil), but DocumentDirectory goes smoothly.